# For every request a new session is getting generated in Yii application

Tags: yii

I know I am either skipping something or configured session incorrectly but Yii sessions are not working for me. I have spent a lot of time in debugging and searching but it doesn't result in any concrete answer.

As described in documentation as well as tutorials over internet I have configured my application session as follows:

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
    // enable cookie-based authentication
    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    'session' => array (
    'sessionName' => 'Site Session',
    'class'=>'CHttpSession',
    'useTransparentSessionID'   =>($_POST['PHPSESSID']) ? true : false,
    'autoStart' => 'true',
    'cookieMode' => 'allow',
    'timeout' => 300
),
```

However each time I am sending a request to server, I get a new session object. I have verified same via `echo "Session id: ".Yii::app()->session->sessionID;`, every time it gives me different id. Also variables which I have added in session previously are not accessible due to this behaviour.

Kindly provide some pointers, I have spent more than 4 hours in debugging and looking for a solution. Tons of thanks for any pointers in advance.

Thanks

~Tarun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could well be just that you have a space in your sessions name.

I've just done a quick test on my working Yii instance, changed the session name to have a space in it, and the cookie value for the session seems to change every time.

Comment: tons of thanks, your solution worked perfectly, just a bit curious how did you figured this out that it's a space issue... actually I have tried several versions of this configuration whatever I found over internet but may be my bad luck. BTW tons of thanks again.

Comment: Just a hunch having never seen a cookie name with a space in. It looks like (in chrome at least) that it replaces the space for a +, which Yii then can't find (because it's looking for a space) and so it generates a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Please read php session name documentation at this url http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

It clearly mentions that session name should contain only alphanumerical characters. That too it should contain at least one alphabet(session name cannot have all its characters as digits also). Otherwise a new session id is generated every time.

Comment: Oh yeah, *clearly*. I guess it could have been made more obvious had this been printed in the Yii guide, or any of the myriad of copy-pasted "guides" on this topic, which instruct the student to configure the session name as "Site Session" with a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

---

chrome 44 and chrome 47's bug , update it to 51,It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note cause I ran into this issue in Yii2. I had a constant `COOKIE_DOMAIN` that was set via php-fpm config and it was for the wrong domain name, causing the session to reset.  Make sure this is set to ".example.com" (including the . at the start to support all your hostnames)

```
'components'=>[
    'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
            'cookieParams' => [
                'path' => '/',
                'domain' => COOKIE_DOMAIN, // <<<--- check this 
                'secure' => true,
            ],
            'writeCallback' => function($session){
                return [
                    'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id
                ];
            },
            'sessionTable' => 'session', // session table name. Defaults to 'session'.
        ],
...
]
```